# Accidentally Erased All My Hard disk During Installing Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally erased all my data from my 1 TB hard disk from my laptop during installing Ubuntu on It. Previously I had two partition . But now I have only one big partition. Didn't copy or save any new files yet. Can you guys help me to get back those files? Is it possible? I would really want to have those data back . PS : I don't have any portable hard disk.

Comment: Do not poweron the system at all until you are ready to proceed with data recovery. Look up (on another system) how to use Testdisk and Photorec to try to recover your lost data. Maybe it will work, maybe not. Either way, it will be lengthy and tedious, and you will wind up purchasing a large external disk. If the lost data is truly valuable to you, look up local professional paid data recovery services.

Comment: Thank you. Do u have experience with test disk and photorec?

Comment: Probably won't help... http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step but you have good backups, yes?